How can I filter outliers in data that is manually recorded?
Different people have to write down values on a certain type of parameter in order to fill out a table, and people obviously tend to write wrong. Sometimes, by a factor of 1000. This creates a lot of outliers that is not related to the data itself but instead human caused error.
Is there any appropriate method for dealing with such outliers? It's difficult to distinguish "real" outliers from ones that were caused by human error.
The data in question:

The parameter in question is "Dose Area Product" (DAP) that is filled out after X-ray of patients in a certain procedure.
The data is skewed towards lower values, but doesn't precisely take on a "fully normal" distribution (although it does look a little bit like it).
The data can not be zero.
All of the data is inputted by different humans, and this causes great uncertainties.

What is an ideal way for filtering outliers and excluding them from the data?
I have tried to:

Manually remove outliers: I stopped doing this because this was a subjective form of filtering, essentially "illegal" I believe. It's also difficult to distinguish "real" outliers from human caused ones.
Box plot: I have tried to calculate Q1, Q3, IQR, lower limit (LL = Q1 - 1,5*IQR) and upper limit (UL = Q3 + 1,5*IQR). I then filter out data that happens to end up outside of the whiskers and boxes. The "problem" I suppose is that the data is non-negative. A disproportionate amount of outliers will be removed near the upper limit, but none are removed from the lower limit because LL always becomes negative and I have no negative data.

Is it "good enough" to just stick with box plots? Or are there actual statistical methods that can be used to objectively "remove" outliers?

Numbers which are obviously wrong by a factor of 1000 can be corrected.  I have several times handled administrative data of deliveries by three companies, supposedly in kg: one would give numbers between 26000 and 28000, one would say 27 or 28, and the third a mixture of those but usually in the larger range.  Since I know each case was a lorry load legally restricted to a maximum weight of 30000 kg (i.e. 30 tonnes) including the cab and it would have been uneconomic to perform tiny deliveries, I simply corrected the numbers and sent yet another reminder on how to complete the form properly.

I personally dislike the term "outlier". There is either actual data, truly coming from your data generating process (DGP), or there is erroneous data, coming from human errors (measurement errors, transcription errors, etc.).
The first kind, you have to keep; after all, would you say that heavy tailed distributions have many outliers? No, they may generate extreme values, but that is in keeping with their underlying distributions. You write that it is "difficult to distinguish "real" outliers from human caused ones": true enough. But what would be these "real outliers"? They would be data from the DGP, coming from your population of interest. You need to keep them (they belong).
The 2nd kind, you can (should?) try to remove (because they are polluting your data; they do not belong), but very carefully, and only if you have some demonstrable evidence. For example, if you are measuring shaft lengths, which you know should be more or less centered on 10cm, if you see a measurement at 10.9, while a little too far for your liking, you can not exclude as an "outlier". But if you see a 109 entry, you can be pretty sure that it probably truly was 10.9, and hence can exclude it (or correct it). But if you see a 13cm entry, while a bit alarming, you have no valid, demonstrable reason to exclude it. So based on context, the specific characteristics of your measurements, their precision, the fundamental of the DGP, etc., you can (and probably should) remove/correct some "operator errors" (so-called outliers...). Beyond that, you should leave the data alone. As you rightly say, any such attempt is a "subjective form of filtering", and should be "essentially "illegal"". No matter which method you use (boxplot, 3-sigma, IQR, etc.), this is just torturing the data until it confesses to whatever you wanted it to say.
